# How to edit content in uploaed war file in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Currently, I have uploaded a war file into AWS from beanstalk. I want to edit the some imformation in applicationContext-datasource.xml in war file. So, how can I edit? Can I edit that information from SSH. But I dont know where is war file is and how to edit. And any other gui to edit the information in war file.

Answer (score 0):

you can ssh to the instance which is generated by the Elastic Beanstalk application But you need to have .pem file to ssh to the ec2 instances, I am not sure you have access to .pem file. usually it will be in /var/lib/tomcat dir. But you can use find command to file the war file. Also its not suggested to edit your files in the server itself. Better make use of the version control management like github or bit bucket